# com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver

All, below is my schema:

```
CREATE TABLE test.lookup_provider_id (
provider_id text,
provider_source text,
gufi text,
PRIMARY KEY (provider_id, provider_source)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (provider_source ASC)
AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
AND comment = ''
AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
AND default_time_to_live = 604800
AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
AND max_index_interval = 2048
AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
AND min_index_interval = 128
AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

Using the Java driver, I perform this kind of query :

```
SELECT gufi FROM test.lookup_provider_id WHERE provider_id = 'id' AND provider_source = 'source';
```

And I get this exception :

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded)
>       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:476)
>       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:455)
>       at com.thales.ecosystem.common.hazelcast.mapstore.LookupProviderIDMapStore.load(LookupProviderIDMapStore.java:145)
>       at com.thales.ecosystem.common.hazelcast.mapstore.LookupProviderIDMapStore.load(LookupProviderIDMapStore.java:42)
>       at com.hazelcast.map.impl.MapStoreWrapper.load(MapStoreWrapper.java:152)
>       at com.hazelcast.map.impl.mapstore.writebehind.WriteBehindStore.load(WriteBehindStore.java:205)
>       at com.hazelcast.map.impl.mapstore.writebehind.WriteBehindStore.load(WriteBehindStore.java:55)
>       at com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.DefaultRecordStore.loadRecordOrNull(DefaultRecordStore.java:398)
>       at com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.DefaultRecordStore.get(DefaultRecordStore.java:612)
>       at com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.GetOperation.run(GetOperation.java:43)
>       at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:186)
>       at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl.run(OperationExecutorImpl.java:382)
>       at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl.runOrExecute(OperationExecutorImpl.java:409)
>       at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.doInvokeLocal(Invocation.java:534)
>       at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.doInvoke(Invocation.java:519)
>       at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.invoke0(Invocation.java:490)
>       at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:200)
>       at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationBuilderImpl.invoke(InvocationBuilderImpl.java:59)
>       at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractPartitionMessageTask.processMessage(AbstractPartitionMessageTask.java:67)
>       at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractMessageTask.initializeAndProcessMessage(AbstractMessageTask.java:123)
>       at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractMessageTask.run(AbstractMessageTask.java:103)
>       at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:142)
>       at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:127)
>       at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.run(OperationThread.java:102)
>   Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded)

I'm using a cluster of 9 Cassandra 3.10 nodes deployed on different VMs (CentOS).
Using nodetool status shows that everything seems to be ok. And I can't see anything in logs that can give a clue on what is happening.

I'm a bit lost, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are the nodes reachable on network from location of you program?

Comment: Yes they are. Not all reads are failing, just some of them at random times.

Comment: Maybe nodes are performing compaction at that time?